# Notepad++ lines with X words in common

Tags: notepad++

I have an array of sentences, that i want to check for any duplicated (or very similar) rows.

i basically want to delete any lines that have X amount of words in common. i want it to ignore any words that are in common that are  less than or equal to 4 letter in length. i want punctuations to be ignored (, . ' : ect...)

i have installed the TextFX plugin and sorted rows by length, and i have many duplicated lines with very minor differences in punctuation /grammar.i could go the list and delete them manual, but that would be an incredible waste of time.

any help is appreciated, thank you for reading.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: i tried searching, but the only things i have been able to found is how to remove lines with/without certain phrases or "regular expressions" or how to remove identical lines. which does not work for me.